# Lightning Component in Communities url redirect

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community-builder

I have a lightning component in community builder that shows a list view of Ideas. I want to link to the custom detail page/component when the title is clicked. I tried using "window.location.href = '/ideadetails';" in my js controller but for some reason that's taking me to the new idea screen (another custom lightning component).

There is another component that I use for users to submit new ideas, but even removing that component from the list view page doesn't resolve the issue.

I did read only that window.location is not supported in lightning so my question is how should I direct the user to the actual detail page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use navigate lightning function to navigate to detail .

```js
navigateToRecord : function (component, event, helper) {
var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
navEvt.setParams({
  "recordId": "00QB0000000ybNX"
});
  navEvt.fire();
}
```

Also note that you can redirect to any URL with a NavigateToURL event

```js
  ({

   navigate : function(component, event, helper) {
    //Find the text value of the component with aura:id set to "address"
    var address = '/s/detail/'+recordId;
    var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    urlEvent.setParams({
      "url": address,
      "isredirect" :false
    });
    urlEvent.fire();
  }

})
```

Comment: Have you tried the force:navigateToURL event? I only ask because SF's documentation states that it's only supported in Salesforce1. Don't want that to break with a future communities update.

Comment: Yes i have used in projects working with communities builder .It will work as community builder is based on lightning component framework .

Comment: Thanks it worked! Wish they'd update their documentation. Wasted so much time searching for this